# Step drawstyle plotly dash

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly, plotly-dash

I created some cool graphs with matplotlib and “drawstyle steps” time on x, categorical data on y and steps betwenn these points like picture below. Is this possible in plotly? I have only found gannt, but thats not what I need, in a kind of a waterfall graph would be nice but I have same category multiple on timeline (x), must not be exact the same but something which I can see how long was the time (in my case timedelta) from one datadot to another

[image]

Comment: Does the example here help? https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/51

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `line_shape` (set to `vh` or `hv`) and `line_dash` like this.

```
import plotly.express as px

fig = px.line(x=[0,1,2,3,4,5], y=[0,1,0,2,0,1])
fig.update_traces(mode="markers+lines", line_shape="vh", line_dash="dash")
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I have a success with using `line_shape` directly on `px.line(..., line_shape='hv')`, despite the docstring states that possible values are: ``One of `'linear'` or `'spline'`.``